# How to multiboot ubuntu 11.10 with another linux?

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, ubuntu-11.10

I have installed centos on my /dev/sda9.

There is windows 7 on my first partition.

Now I try to install ubuntu on /dev/sda11

While installing,it shows the following error.

> migration-assistant needs to mount a partition,but cannot do so because the following mount point could not be mounted:
>
> /dev/sda9
>
> please close any application using this mount points.
>
> would you like migration-assistant to try to unmount these partition again?

How do I address this error?

Comment: Do you do a fresh install of Ubuntu from a CD or USB? I am asking because it mentions "migration-assistant", which sounds like you try to get some settings from your centos or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install Ubuntu on your system by following steps:

1. Boot your system with Ubuntu Live CD
2. Select 'try Ubuntu'
3. Open terminal and type `sudo ubiquity --no-migration-assistant`
4. Follow with the installation window as usual.

This means you need to disable migration assistant, so you cannot import informations from user and Firefox in CentOS. That's all.